# Stack overflow when cancelling a thread that is waiting on epoll

Tags: linux, multithreading, gcc, stack-overflow, address-sanitizer

I began getting stack errors using Valgrind and Address Sanitizer with GCC 10.3 and x64_64 Ubuntu 21.04 in C language. The code tested was a few thousands of lines long so I made a very simple test suite representing the problem, though with a different kind of a message:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* func(void* epoll) {
  struct epoll_event events[1];
  epoll_wait(*((int*) epoll), events, 1, -1);
  return NULL;
}

int main() {
  int sfd = epoll_create1(0);
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, func, &sfd);
  sleep(1);
  pthread_cancel(thread);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with: `gcc test.c -o test -pthread -Wall -pedantic -O3 -g -fsanitize=undefined,address && ./test`

On my machine I am getting the following error:

```
=================================================================
==143640==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_thread.cpp:367 "((ptr[0] == kCurrentStackFrameMagic)) != (0)" (0x0, 0x0)
    #0 0x7fceb3d6ad68 in AsanCheckFailed ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_rtl.cpp:74
    #1 0x7fceb3d8b69e in __sanitizer::CheckFailed(char const*, int, char const*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_termination.cpp:78
    #2 0x7fceb3d704ec in __asan::AsanThread::GetStackFrameAccessByAddr(unsigned long, __asan::AsanThread::StackFrameAccess*) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_thread.cpp:367
    #3 0x7fceb3cdaeab in __asan::GetStackAddressInformation(unsigned long, unsigned long, __asan::StackAddressDescription*) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_descriptions.cpp:203
    #4 0x7fceb3cdc2e8 in __asan::AddressDescription::AddressDescription(unsigned long, unsigned long, bool) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_descriptions.cpp:455
    #5 0x7fceb3cdc2e8 in __asan::AddressDescription::AddressDescription(unsigned long, unsigned long, bool) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_descriptions.cpp:439
    #6 0x7fceb3cdea94 in __asan::ErrorGeneric::ErrorGeneric(unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool, unsigned long) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_errors.cpp:389
    #7 0x7fceb3d6a385 in __asan::ReportGenericError(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool, unsigned long, unsigned int, bool) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_report.cpp:476
    #8 0x7fceb3d01038 in __interceptor_sigaltstack ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:9996
    #9 0x7fceb3d7fbfd in __sanitizer::UnsetAlternateSignalStack() ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_posix_libcdep.cpp:194
    #10 0x7fceb3d6f9ec in __asan::AsanThread::Destroy() ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_thread.cpp:104
    #11 0x7fceb3321430 in __nptl_deallocate_tsd nptl/pthread_create.c:303
    #12 0x7fceb3322470 in __nptl_deallocate_tsd nptl/pthread_create.c:258
    #13 0x7fceb3322470 in start_thread nptl/pthread_create.c:484
    #14 0x7fceb3244d52 in clone (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x117d52)
```

I was not able to recreate the error using semaphores, but in my thousands-of-lines code I was also receiving an error on a `sem_wait()`.

After doing some debugging, I have noticed it is the very `epoll_wait()` call that creates problems for some reason. It doesn't work with `sleep()` or other such "simple" functions so to say. The problem only exists while the thread is sleeping, but I have not monitored any cases in which the thread wasn't sleeping so I can't say much in this case.

It is very annoying to deal with this problem, because I was actually trying to solve a different problem, and accidentally ran into this one while using the sanitizer. It has never caused me any problems in production code so far.

The problem disappears when using `-fstack-protector-all`. Changing compilation level (`-O`) doesn't seem to affect it. The sanitize reports the error 100% of the time.

### The `sem_wait()` case

I just recreated the other error with stack using `sem_wait()`, by making the test suite a bit more similar to the production code. Here is the test:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <signal.h>

void* func(void* data) {
  {
    sigset_t mask;
    (void) sigfillset(&mask);
    (void) pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL);
  }
  sem_wait(data);
  return NULL;
}

int main() {
  sem_t sem = {0};
  sem_init(&sem, 0, 0);
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, func, &sem);
  sleep(1);
  pthread_cancel(thread);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

The error:

```
=================================================================
==144764==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope on address 0x7f0788ffed00 at pc 0x7f078d376017 bp 0x7f0788ffecd0 sp 0x7f0788ffe478
WRITE of size 24 at 0x7f0788ffed00 thread T16777215
    #0 0x7f078d376016 in __interceptor_sigaltstack ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:9996
    #1 0x7f078d3f4bfd in __sanitizer::UnsetAlternateSignalStack() ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_posix_libcdep.cpp:194
    #2 0x7f078d3e49ec in __asan::AsanThread::Destroy() ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_thread.cpp:104
    #3 0x7f078c996430 in __nptl_deallocate_tsd nptl/pthread_create.c:303
    #4 0x7f078c997470 in __nptl_deallocate_tsd nptl/pthread_create.c:258
    #5 0x7f078c997470 in start_thread nptl/pthread_create.c:484
    #6 0x7f078c8b9d52 in clone (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x117d52)

Address 0x7f0788ffed00 is located in stack of thread T1 at offset 112 in frame
    #0 0x5563006ca5ef in func (/home/franek/c/git/shnet/dev/test+0x15ef)

AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer: nested bug in the same thread, aborting.
```

And actually, this is the very specific configuration that appears to be triggering the error, because when I get rid of the block around the 3 signal-setting lines like so:

```c
void* func(void* data) {
  sigset_t mask;
  (void) sigfillset(&mask);
  (void) pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL);
  sem_wait(data);
  return NULL;
}
```

..., the error magically disappears.

With production code, I was also occassionally getting `stack-overflow` and other stack-errors when experimenting with `-fstack-protector`. All were pretty much about the same thing though.

Well... look. I am no expert on this one, but I collected as much meaningful data as I could. Please send help.

### The error without `sem_wait()`

Looks like this error is reproducible without semaphores:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>

void* func(void* data) {
  {
    sigset_t mask;
    (void) sigfillset(&mask);
    (void) pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL);
  }
  sleep(999);
  return NULL;
}

int main() {
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, func, NULL);
  sleep(1);
  pthread_cancel(thread);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reporting it on the gcc mailing lists?  It might be a known bug or limitation of AddressSanitizer.  The code itself looks okay to me.

Comment: I have been experimenting for quite a while now. I think I will ignore the error for now. I am getting the errors with clang too, and after upgrading to GCC 11.1. I have not found a similar bug, but I will look further, and eventually submit a bug to the GCC team. Thanks for the suggestion. @NateEldredge

Comment: @shadministrator Note that main development happens in clang community and later backported to GCC so you have more luck with reporting clang bug at https://github.com/google/sanitizers

Comment: fwiw: we have a very similar problem - same stack walk, but it manifests as a stack buffer overflow of 24 bytes instead when the function exits.  If we don't use pthread_cancel, it doesn't happen (the thread is in recvfrom()).  We opted to turn off the sanitizer for that fnc for gcc 10.3 builds.

Comment: just hit similar problem after upgrading gcc from 9.4 to 11.2

==21617==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7fffe79c9c40 at pc 0x7ffff7610fc7 bp 0x7fffe79c9c10 sp 0x7fffe79c93b8
WRITE of size 24 at 0x7fffe79c9c40 thread T16777215
    #0 0x7ffff7610fc6 in __interceptor_sigaltstack ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:9986
    #1 0x7ffff768f867 in __sanitizer::UnsetAlternateSignalStack() ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_posix_libcdep.cpp:195
    #2 0x7ffff767f60c in __asan::AsanThread::Destroy()

Comment: turning off instrumentation in functions using epoll_wait helped to alleviate it, see https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer#turning-off-instrumentation